# how to host Angular 7 App on Dell ECS object store

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, url-rewriting

We are trying to host Angular 7 app on ECS object store. We have tried with static HTML pages with one to one mapping on files. This works perfectly fine.

issue comes when angular routing comes into picture as there is no file for given path.

for example, if base URL is: http://example.com/index.html
browser serve this just fine but when we navigate to any other part of application it gives us error like "no such key" as below...

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Resource><bucket-name>/somepath</Resource>
<RequestId>some resource id </RequestId>
</Error>
```

in case of, amazon S3, we can provide default/error/fallback url to back to index.html but how can we do this in case DELL ECS.

I already added fallback URL in angular app like if path not found redirect user to index.html.

but request is not even reaching to angular app. ECS object store itself rejecting it.